# Is there a Lambda Else condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, lambda

I am using lambda statement to set up my foreach loop:

```
foreach (Shape shape in shapefile.Where(x=>x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue))
```

`IgnoreField` and `IgnoreValue` are **OPTIONAL** parameters.

If those fields are blank (not used) how could I alter my foreach to account for that?  Is there an Else statement or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Shape shape in shapefile.Where(x=>IgnoreField==null || IngoreValue==null || x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue))
```

Comment: how do I explain how this works?  This looks to be like the answer I'm looking for, I just want the ability to explain it so I can remind myself in notes later.

Comment: This expression is same as yours with 2 additional condition to check whether global IgnoreField and IgnoreValue parameters are null or not. So if any of these parameter is null, all the items will be retrieved. If both are not null, all the items will be filtered by the condition.

Comment: Since `IgnoreField` and `IngoreValue` don't change during the iteration it would be best to check them before iterating, rather than for each value in `shapefile`.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is... if they are not null... then check them...  but if they are null then ignore them right?

```
foreach (Shape shape in shapefile.Where(x=>
   x.IgnoreField == null ||
   x.IgnoreValue == null ||
   x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue)
```

Also notice how when you indent your LinQ it is so much easier to see what it's doing?

Another formatting technique I use, especially on a foreach statement like this is to store the enumerable in an appropriately named variable before using it in the foreach statement like so...

```
var shapesFilteredByIgnores = shapefile.Where(x=>
   x.IgnoreField == null ||
   x.IgnoreValue == null ||
   x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue)

foreach (Shape shape in shapesFilteredByIgnores)
```

Of course this is only clearer if you have a meaningful variable name to assign it to.

Comment: I think the second `null` checks are unnecessary since you can't get that far if either one is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not magic. Use exactly what you would have used outside of the lambda:

```
foreach (Shape shape in shapefile.Where(x=>
   (x.IgnoreField != null && // If both optional fields are present
   x.IgnoreValue != null &&
   x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue) // Then only where metadata for 
                                              // ignored field is not the ignored value
   ||
   (x.IgnoreField == null || x.IgnoreValue == null))) // But if either field absent
                                                      // then return all data
```

Comment: That doesn't look optional to me... What am I not getting?

Comment: The OP didn't say which data he wants to retrieve if one of the two optional fields is absent. I'll change it to return all rows when one of the optional fields is absent.

Comment: IgnoreField and IgnoreValue are not part of the shapefile they are truely global variables populated via an ini file.  I wasn't clear enough on that.  So I think I can use everything from the || part.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply apply the `Where` conditionally based on whether or not you have values to check:

```
var query = shapefile.AsEnumerable();

if(IgnoreField!=null && IngoreValue!=null)
    query = query.Where(x=>x.GetMetadata(IgnoreField) != IgnoreValue);

foreach (Shape shape in query)
    {...}
```

Unlike the other answers here, this doesn't bother to check the two fields for `null` for each item in the sequence; it checks them once and applies the filter only if it's able to.